# Jest tests with i18next and storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, i18next

I use i18next in my component repo. Components are working fine, but I have problems with tests. I use i18next with hoc, when I export only component, tests are passing, but when I export it like export default translate ('components') (List); tests failed. I tried to make two exports, with hoc and without but some components are used in the other and I can't import it without hoc. My architecture looks like: Root component with I18nextProvider, I have wrapped every component in story by this component, it's main component in my main app. Looks just like that:

```
const Root = ({ component, i18 }) => (
  <I18nextProvider i18n={i18}>
    <div className={bindClasses('wrapper')}>
      {component}
    </div>
  </I18nextProvider>
);
```

example component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
import classNameBind from 'classnames/bind';
import styles from './List.css';
import Icon from '../Icon';
import uuid from '../../utils/methods/uuid';

class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: props.items,
    };
  }

  renderNoItems() {
    const { items, t } = this.props;

    return items.length === 0 ?
      t('noMatchingFoundLabel') : '';
  }

  renderItems() {
    const { onItemSelected } = this.props;
    const { items } = this.state;

    return items
      .map(element =>
        (
          <li key={uuid()}>
            <a role="button" tabIndex={0} onClick={() => onItemSelected(element)}>
              { element.icon ? <Icon {...element.icon} /> : '' }
              {element.name}
            </a>
          </li>
        ),
      );
  }

  render() {
    const { className } = this.props;
    const bindClasses = classNameBind.bind(styles);

    return (
      <nav
        ref={(scrollable) => { this.scrollable = scrollable; }}
        className={bindClasses('wrapper', className)}
        onScroll={this.handleScroll}
      >
        <ul>
          {this.renderItems()}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default translate('components')(List);
```

every component have index.js file just with export default.

usage in story:

```
<Root i18={i18}>
    <List />
</Root>
```

I'm not sure here. Should I pass t function to List component? it works without it but maybe I should.
And test:

```
import React from 'react';
import List from '../List';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Icon from "../../Icon";
import TextField from "../../TextField";

describe("List component", () => {
  const defaultPropsWithIcons = {
    items: [
      { name: 'Item1', icon: { name: 'upload', color: 'default' }, options: { some: 'options1'} },
      { name: 'Item2', icon: { name: 'upload', color: 'default' }, options: { some: 'options2'} },
    ],
    t: jest.fn(),
  };

  test("should render List component with passed items with icons", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<List {...defaultPropsWithIcons} />);
    const actionList = wrapper.find('.wrapper');

    expect(list.find('ul').children().length).toBe(2);
    expect(list.find('ul').children().at(0).find('a').exists());
     expect(list.find('ul').children().at(0).find(Icon).exists()).toBe(true);
  });
```

With normal export of component it's working, with translate it failed.
I tried use

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
    receive the t function as a prop
    translate: () => List => props => <List t={() => ''} {...props} />,
  }));
```

or

```
const wrapper = shallow(<List {...defaultPropsWithIcons} t={key => key} />);
```

but it's not helping, still got error at 1st expect (expected to be 2, received 0)
Anyone have idea how I should test it? or where I have mistake in i18next usage? Got same problem on every test where I use List component in another component or just in other components with i18next.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You should not test components wrapped in HOCs, it's just since a unit test should test individual part of your code.

> In computer programming, unit testing is a software testing method by
>   which individual units of source code. 
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

Try to avoid using { mount } from jest, I suspect that you're having troubles when you use it because it renders child components.

In case you want to have integration test and render ne=sted component you can use mock like so:

```
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
    translate: () => List => props => <List t={() => ''} {...props} />,
  }));
```

**UPDATE:**

You can test translate component if you don't like imports being marked as unused:

```
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
    translate: jest.fn(() => List => props => <List t={() => ''} {...props} />),
  }));

test('should test translation', () => {
    expect(translate).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(translate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('components');
  });
```

Hope it will help, happy coding!

Comment: I used this mock before and tests still failing... I don't have idea for that

Comment: In your code, I don't see import { translate } from 'react-i18next', you should do it explicitly in order to mock dependency

Comment: I know I know, forgot to say I added import ;) but still nothing. And I don't know why import is marked as unused anyway.

Comment: just because it unused :) use it like in the update, and try to avoid using jest.mount it's a source of your problem...You can also try passing translation as a context, not sure if it's a case. Please provide the error description

Comment: With your update I have  

    expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalled()  
    
    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.  
    Received:  
      function: [Function translate]

Comment: Make sure you're using jest.mock before "describe", right after imports

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. Now 'should test translation' passed but still have error in 1st test, expect(received).toBe(expected)
    

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      2
    Received:
      0
      
      at Object.<anonymous> (lib/components/List/__tests__/List.jsx:32:53)
          at Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Comment: try to console log wrapper.html(), you might have an issue with selectors in .find method

Comment: wrapper.html-> <nav class="wrapper"><ul><li><a role="button"><span role="button" class="icon icon-default default">test-file-stub</span>Item1</a></li><li><a role="button"><span role="button" class="icon icon-default default">test-file-stub</span>Item2</a></li></ul></nav>, looks fine but when I  console log list (const list = wrapper.find('.wrapper');) with .html() i got error  Method “html” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.

Comment: .wrapper is a root element, you can not find it inside itself, go for .find(‘ul’)

Comment: same error. when i console.log it without .html() I got ShallowWrapper { length: 0 }.  Without translate HOC it have length 1. Maybe i'll try to refactor translations to render prop, not translation hoc...